# Where do I use notifydatasetchanged in my code? Need for my ListView to automatically update itself after list item deletion

Tags: android, listview, android-cursor, notifydatasetchanged

I know this has been discussed extensively on StackOverflow, and on the internet in general, but I can't find any good, solid information that helps me with my situation. At least none that I can understand and translate for my situation.

I have data in the database that I am retrieving with a `Cursor`. I am sticking this data into a `ListView` within a `Fragment`. On each line of my list, there is a button I use to delete that item. This all works, but I cannot figure out how to use `notifydatasetchanged` so that the `ListView` automatically refreshes itself, and the user can see that the deletion took place.

I have the List embedded in a `SwipeRefreshLayout` and the list item does disappear when I swipe it after deletion. However, what I want is for the list to automatically update on its own, which is what I thought the `notifydatasetchanged` was supposed to provide. Is this not the case? Is my understanding of `notifydatasetchanged` 100% incorrect?

Anyway, here is what I have:

My **Home.java** fragment:

```
public class Home extends Fragment{

    private MainActivity mainActivity;
    private View rootView;
    private SwipeRefreshLayout personSwipeRefresh;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home, container, false);
        personSwipeRefresh = (SwipeRefreshLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.person_swipe_refresh);

        mainActivity = (MainActivity)getActivity();

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View rootView, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(rootView, savedInstanceState);
        drawThePersonView();

        personSwipeRefresh.setColorSchemeColors(Color.parseColor(Constants.RED), Color.parseColor(Constants.ORANGE), Color.parseColor(Constants.YELLOW), Color.parseColor(Constants.GREEN), Color.parseColor(Constants.BLUE), Color.parseColor(Constants.INDIGO), Color.parseColor(Constants.VIOLET));
        personSwipeRefresh.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                personSwipeRefresh.setRefreshing(false);
                drawThePersonView();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        drawThePersonView();
    }

    public void drawThePersonView(){
        Context context = getContext();
        DatabaseHelper myDBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
        Cursor personCursor = myDBHelper.getPersonCursor();
        String[] fromColumns = {"_id","personNumber","location","status"};
        int[] toViews = {R.id.person_number_textview, R.id.personNumber_textview, R.id.person_location_textview, R.id.person_status_textview};
        CustomSimpleCursorAdapter mySimpleCursorAdapter = new CustomSimpleCursorAdapter(context, R.layout.person_layout, personCursor, fromColumns, toViews, 0, mainActivity);

        ListView myListView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.person_row);

        // Draw the list
        myListView.setAdapter(mySimpleCursorAdapter);

        myDBHelper.close();
    }
}
```

My **CustomSimpleCursorAdapter.java**

```
public class CustomSimpleCursorAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {

    private Context context;

    public CustomSimpleCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor cursor, String[] from, int[] to, int flags) {
        super(context, layout, cursor, from, to, flags);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        DatabaseHelper dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
        View row = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

        cursor.moveToPosition(position);
        final Integer ID = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id"));
        final String PERSON_NUMBER = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("personNumber"));

        // Make the delete button clickable.
        Button deletePersonButton = (Button)row.findViewById(R.id.remove_person);
        deletePersonButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                DatabaseHelper databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
                databaseHelper.deletePerson(PERSON_NUMBER);
            }
        });

        return row;
    }
}
```

Here is something I did try that I thought would work, but it did not:

```
Button deletePersonButton = (Button)row.findViewById(R.id.remove_person);
final CustomSimpleCursorAdapter csca = (CustomSimpleCursorAdapter)this;
...
databaseHelper.deletePerson(PERSON_NUMBER);
csca.notifydatasetchanged();
```

Thank you for taking the time to read this.

Have a good day. :-)

---

**UPDATE:** I found out my issue is that my `cursor` does not refresh when I delete from the database. If I had 5 items in the list before deletion, the `cursor.getCount()` says **5**, but after I delete the item from the database, the `cursor.getCount()`` still says **5**. How do I get my cursor to refresh from within my custom SimpleCursorAdapter?

Comment: Try to update notifydatasetchanged() on UI thread.

Comment: @patelvatsal In my Home.java `Fragment`?

Comment: `getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                csca.notifydatasetchanged();
            }
        });` Update this code in your code.

Comment: @patelvatsal I am not able to do this from within my `View.OnClickListener` of my custom SimpleCursorAdapter (no access to getActivity()). Should I be doing it there or somewhere else?

Comment: ` ((Activity) context).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        csca.notifydatasetchanged();
                    }
                });`  try with this.

Comment: @patelvatsal That did not work. Thanks for the assistance.